# Stars and bars confusion, they have a slightly different answer to me.

Tags: combinatorics

I have a problem:

> A family has six children, A,B,C,D,E,F. The ages of these six children are added together to make an integer less than $32$ where none of the children are less than one year old.

What is the chances of guessing the ages of all of the children.

I thought stars and bars, and this is equivalent to choosing $7$ children for $$x_1+\dots+x_7=31$$

So we get (1 in)${31-1 \choose 7-1}$

But they said that $x_1+\dots+\dots+x_7=32$ is correct. I feel like that would be the case if the original question said $x_1+\dots+x_6\leq32$, but it said $x_1+\dots+x_6\lt32$

So apparently that makes it (1 in)${32-1 \choose 7-1}$

Which is right?(Probably them I know, but I want to know why mine is wrong please)

Comment: While this is a valid combinatorics question, I think it completely disqualifies as a probability question. The implicit assumption that all possible outcomes that we can (or care to) distinguish must be equally likely seems like the antithesis of probability theory. In the given example the outcome $(1,1,1,1,1,26)$ though allowed seems much less likely than a more uniform age distribution. Even apart from actual demographics, it is hard to think of any _theoretic_ selection model (involving independent trial) that would make all outcomes equally probable. Short of making a list & picking one.

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen , yes sorry, Andre pointed out this, I forgot to remove the (impractical) probability tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the sum at $31$, you’re allowing the extra variable $x_7$ to be $0$. However, the formula that you’re using is for the number of solutions in strictly **positive** integers, so you want to make sure that $x_7$ will have to be at least $1$. You do this by insisting that the total be $32$ rather than $31$.

Comment: Yes, very true. Else I would need to reduce all the others to $x_i\geq 0$ and use the ${n+r-1 \choose n}$ formula. All answers were good, thanks everyone(I can't upvote yet)

Comment: @Combinatorics: Yes, that’s exactly right. You’re welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We want to solve $x_1+\cdots+x_7=32$, where all the $x_i$ are $\ge 1$. For $x_7\ge 1$, which means $x_1+\cdots +x_6\lt 32$.

If you use $31$, then since $x_7\ge 1$, the ages of the real children would be forced to add up to less than $31$.

**Remark:** This answers the Stars and Bars question. However, that question has little connection with the motivating question about the chances of guessing the ages of the children. For one thing the ages are a monotone sequence of integers, with equalities relatively unlikely.

Comment: $6$ bars, $32$ stars? Is your remark referring to practical likelihood of twins etc? If so you are right, I will remove the probability tag.

Comment: A guess would be a say non-decreasing sequence of ages. That is a *partition* and partitions with sum $\le 31$ are *not* counted using Stars and Bars. This is aside from the twin problem.

Comment: How would I work out the problem with this alternative interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

given $$\sum_i^6x_i<32\implies \sum_i^7x_i=31(\because x_7\ge0,x_{(i,0\le i\le6)}\ge1)$$
let $$x_7'=x_7+1,x_7'\ge1$$
so $$\sum_i^6x_i+x_7'=32$$
now all $x_i\ge1$, now you can solve it maybe?